Sending values to the hardware interface from a subscriber
I have a subscriber which subscribes the steering angle from the ackermann steering controller and send this value to the hardware interface via shared pointer, i am able to get the value inside the interface function from set_position_command function but when i pass this value to the hardware interface write function its not working.
my subscriber cpp
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <control_msgs/msg/steering_controller_status.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include "kaipulla_firmware/kaipulla_interface.hpp"

using namespace std::placeholders;

class SteeringAngleSubscriber : public rclcpp::Node {
public:
  SteeringAngleSubscriber(std::shared_ptr<kaipulla_firmware::KaipullaInterface> kaipulla_interface)
      : Node("steering_angle_subscriber"), kaipulla_interface_(kaipulla_interface) {
    subscription_ = create_subscription<control_msgs::msg::SteeringControllerStatus>(
        "/kaipulla_controller/controller_state",
        10,  // Adjust queue size as needed (optional)
        std::bind(&SteeringAngleSubscriber::callback, this, _1));
  }

private:
  void callback(const control_msgs::msg::SteeringControllerStatus::SharedPtr msg) {
    double steering_angle = 0, servo_value = 0;
    if (!msg->steering_angle_command.empty()) {
      steering_angle = msg->steering_angle_command[0];
      servo_value = (steering_angle + 1.5) * (50.0 / 3.0);
      RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("SteeringAngleSubscriber"), "Received steering angle command: %f, servo value: %f", steering_angle, servo_value);
    }
    kaipulla_interface_->set_position_command(servo_value);
  }

  rclcpp::Subscription<control_msgs::msg::SteeringControllerStatus>::SharedPtr subscription_;
  std::shared_ptr<kaipulla_firmware::KaipullaInterface> kaipulla_interface_;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  auto kaipulla_interface = std::make_shared<kaipulla_firmware::KaipullaInterface>();
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<SteeringAngleSubscriber>(kaipulla_interface));
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}

my hardware interface hpp
#ifndef KAIPULLA_INTERFACE_HPP
#define KAIPULLA_INTERFACE_HPP

#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <hardware_interface/system_interface.hpp>
#include <libserial/SerialPort.h>
#include <rclcpp_lifecycle/state.hpp>
#include <rclcpp_lifecycle/node_interfaces/lifecycle_node_interface.hpp>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace kaipulla_firmware {

using CallbackReturn = rclcpp_lifecycle::node_interfaces::LifecycleNodeInterface::CallbackReturn;

class KaipullaInterface : public hardware_interface::SystemInterface {
public:
  KaipullaInterface();
  virtual ~KaipullaInterface();

  // Implementing rclcpp_lifecycle::node_interfaces::LifecycleNodeInterface
  virtual CallbackReturn on_activate(const rclcpp_lifecycle::State &) override;
  virtual CallbackReturn on_deactivate(const rclcpp_lifecycle::State &) override;
  void set_position_command(double value);

  // Implementing hardware_interface::SystemInterface
  virtual CallbackReturn on_init(const hardware_interface::HardwareInfo &hardware_info) override;
  virtual std::vector<hardware_interface::StateInterface> export_state_interfaces() override;
  virtual std::vector<hardware_interface::CommandInterface> export_command_interfaces() override;
  virtual hardware_interface::return_type read(const rclcpp::Time &, const rclcpp::Duration &) override;
  virtual hardware_interface::return_type write(const rclcpp::Time &, const rclcpp::Duration &) override;

private:
  LibSerial::SerialPort arduino_;
  std::string port_;
  std::vector<double> velocity_commands_;
  std::vector<double> position_states_;
  std::vector<double> velocity_states_;
  std::vector<double> position_commands_;
 
  std::mutex steering_angle_mutex_;
  double steering_angle_;
};

} // namespace kaipulla_firmware

#endif  // KAIPULLA_INTERFACE_HPP

my hardware interface
#include "kaipulla_firmware/kaipulla_interface.hpp"
#include <hardware_interface/types/hardware_interface_type_values.hpp>
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <control_msgs/msg/steering_controller_status.hpp>

namespace kaipulla_firmware {

KaipullaInterface::KaipullaInterface() : steering_angle_(0.0) {}

KaipullaInterface::~KaipullaInterface() {}

void KaipullaInterface::set_position_command(double value) {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(steering_angle_mutex_);
  steering_angle_ = value;
  std::stringstream message_stream;
  message_stream << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << value << ':' << steering_angle_;
  RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("KaipullaInterface"), "Got steering angle: " << message_stream.str());
}

CallbackReturn KaipullaInterface::on_init(const hardware_interface::HardwareInfo &hardware_info) {
  CallbackReturn result = hardware_interface::SystemInterface::on_init(hardware_info);
  if (result != CallbackReturn::SUCCESS) {
    return result;
  }

  size_t num_joints = info_.joints.size();
  velocity_commands_.resize(num_joints, 0.0);
  position_states_.resize(num_joints, 0.0);
  velocity_states_.resize(num_joints, 0.0);
  position_commands_.resize(num_joints, 0.0);

  return CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
}

std::vector<hardware_interface::StateInterface> KaipullaInterface::export_state_interfaces() {
  std::vector<hardware_interface::StateInterface> state_interfaces;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < info_.joints.size(); i++) {
    state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(
        info_.joints[i].name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION, &position_states_[i]));
    state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(
        info_.joints[i].name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &velocity_states_[i]));
  }

  return state_interfaces;
}

std::vector<hardware_interface::CommandInterface> KaipullaInterface::export_command_interfaces() {
  std::vector<hardware_interface::CommandInterface> command_interfaces;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < info_.joints.size(); i++) {
    command_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::CommandInterface(
        info_.joints[i].name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &velocity_commands_[i]));
    command_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::CommandInterface(
        info_.joints[i].name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION, &position_commands_[i]));
  }

  return command_interfaces;
}

CallbackReturn KaipullaInterface::on_activate(const rclcpp_lifecycle::State &) {
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("KaipullaInterface"), "Starting robot hardware ...");

  velocity_commands_ = {0.0, 0.0};
  position_states_ = {0.0, 0.0};
  velocity_states_ = {0.0, 0.0};
  position_commands_ = {0.0, 0.0};

  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("KaipullaInterface"), "Hardware started, ready to take commands");
  return CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
}

CallbackReturn KaipullaInterface::on_deactivate(const rclcpp_lifecycle::State &) {
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("KaipullaInterface"), "Stopping robot hardware ...");
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("KaipullaInterface"), "Hardware stopped");
  return CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
}

hardware_interface::return_type KaipullaInterface::read(const rclcpp::Time &, const rclcpp::Duration &) {
  // Reading logic (omitted for brevity)
  return hardware_interface::return_type::OK;
}

hardware_interface::return_type KaipullaInterface::write(const rclcpp::Time &, const rclcpp::Duration &) {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(steering_angle_mutex_);
  std::stringstream message_stream;
  char direction = velocity_commands_.at(0) >= 0 ? 'F' : 'R';

  std::string compensate_zeros_right = std::abs(velocity_commands_.at(0)) < 10.0 ? "0" : "";
  std::string compensate_zeros_left = std::abs(velocity_commands_.at(1)) < 10.0 ? "0" : "";

  if (velocity_commands_.at(0) == 0) direction = 'S';

  message_stream << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << direction << ':'
                 << std::abs(velocity_commands_.at(0)) << ":"
                 << std::abs(steering_angle_);

  RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("KaipullaInterface"), "Sending to hardware " << message_stream.str());
  return hardware_interface::return_type::OK;
}

} // namespace kaipulla_firmware

PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(kaipulla_firmware::KaipullaInterface, hardware_interface::SystemInterface)

values are updating on the set_position_command but it is not updating on return_type KaipullaInterface::write function
[steering_angle_subscriber-7] [INFO] [1716304773.251230129] [SteeringAngleSubscriber]: Received steering angle command: 0.000000, servo value: 25.000000
[steering_angle_subscriber-7] [INFO] [1716304773.251403574] [KaipullaInterface]: Got steering angle: 25.000:25.000
[ros2_control_node-6] [INFO] [1716304773.260664765] [KaipullaInterface]: Sending to hardware S:0.000:0.000
[steering_angle_subscriber-7] [INFO] [1716304773.261277916] [SteeringAngleSubscriber]: Received steering angle command: 0.000000, servo value: 25.000000
[steering_angle_subscriber-7] [INFO] [1716304773.261397852] [KaipullaInterface]: Got steering angle: 25.000:25.000
[ros2_control_node-6] [INFO] [1716304773.270582079] [KaipullaInterface]: Sending to hardware S:0.000:0.000
[steering_angle_subscriber-7] [INFO] [1716304773.271061553] [SteeringAngleSubscriber]: Received steering angle command: 0.000000, servo value: 25.000000
[steering_angle_subscriber-7] [INFO] [1716304773.271174330] [KaipullaInterface]: Got steering angle: 25.000:25.000

how can i debug this?my end goal is to send the steering angle to the serial port using hardware interface write function.I am beginner to ROS and suggest me any other way(if any) to achieve this goal.,thanks

You don't need to write a subscriber creating an instance of your hardware component. Instead, the controller_manager is loading the hardware component plugin for you.
Have you had a look at the demos of ros2_control? For example this carlike bot here should give you a good overview. Adapt the hardware component to read/write to your serial interface.
